# Get reference frame with y axis pointing to magnetic north

Tags: ios, core-motion, cmattitude

With CoreMotion, is it possible to get a reference frame with the Y axis pointing to magnetic north? I would like to make the readings similiar to the ones from Android, which has the Y axis pointing to magnetic north. Thanks in advance.